# Tag info in teams redirects to Stack Overflow main site while editing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

While asking a question in Stack Overflow teams, I noticed that the links for tag info is incorrect.

Please see below screenshot:

[image]

Clicking on info icon in the above example redirects to a 404.

**Note** after posting, the tag is linked to the correct URL and goes to the right tag page.

Comment: thanks for reporting this! we're digging into this bug now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this now, so I'm going to guess this got fixed at some point. Thanks for the report!